# My computer is reading everything

Tags: windows-10

My computer is reading every thing out load:

- the things I type
- the page I'm on
- things that are highlighted on mouse over.

What is this Feature?
What did I do to activate this feature ? *I was trying to refresh a Page with F5*
How do I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quickest way to do it:

Hold the <kbd>Windows</kbd> Key and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Can you indicate source for this?

Comment: @DaveM  I corrected my mistake. I forgot to include the Ctrl key

Comment: Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 4):

it's a narrator.

to turn on / off :

settings -> Ease of Acccess -> narrator -> on/off

Comment: Full list of Narrator commands at https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/22806